# values are passing when datatype is different in karate

Tags: karate

When we are providing the input whose datatype is boolean passed in **POST** API and validating it with **GET** API which return value in string
eg:

```
* def a = 'false' // result from GET API
* def b = false  //input
* match a == b
```

Expected Result : It should fail as the datatype is different 
Actual Result ":  scenario is showing PASS
Why is it passing?

whereas, I also noticed when I an validating the data from database whose column datatype is string and we are matching the data with boolean value 
i.e

```
* match 'false' == false
```

Expected Result : It should fail
Actual Result : scenario is failed

Comment: nope: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is related to this https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1179

seems like it has been fixed recently. you can build the code following this https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide#build, else it will be next release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this option to check for if else inside a feature

```
    Scenario: if else
      * def val = 'test'
#      * def result = <condition> ? <true value> : <false value>
      * def result = val == 'test' ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
      * print result
```